# How to Retrieve MongoDb collection Id with Monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, koa, swig-template, monk

I'm trying to do a very simple app 'todo app' on koajs with swig and I have succeeded in inserting data to Mongodb, in my case the name of the db is 'mytodos' and the collection is 'todos'.

How can I retrieve the '_id' of a document? I tried doing this:

index.html (this lists the todo items)

```
<div class="todoListClass">
  <p>
    <strong>Your todo list:</strong> {{todos.length}}
    {% for todo in todos%}
    <li>{{todo.text1}} <span>
    <a href="/todo/delete/{{todo._id}}">Delete</a></span></li>
    {%endfor%}
  </p>
</div>
```

but I can't seem to get the result that I want. It just returns '[Object][object]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_id` field of your todo item is loaded from mongodb for displaying the `_id` field which is of type ObjectId you will need to get a string representation by calling `_id.toString()`.

```
<div class="todoListClass">
  <p>
    <strong>Your todo list:</strong> {{todos.length}}
    {% for todo in todos%}
    <li>{{todo.text1}} <span>
    <a href="/todo/delete/{{todo._id.toString()}}">Delete</a></span></li>
    {%endfor%}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome! that fixed it! Thanks!